# Use of validators for simple validations

Tags: java, validation, java-ee

I've been working in Liferay code, and I've come across this construct a few times:

```
List<?> list;
...
if (Validator.isNotNull(list)) {
    //do stuff
}}
```

The source code for `Validator.java` looks like this:

```
public static boolean isNotNull(Object obj) {
    return !isNull(obj);
}

public static boolean isNull(String obj) {
    ...
}

public static boolean isNull(Long obj) {
    ...
}

public static boolean isNull(Integer obj) {
    ...
}

public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof String) {
        return isNull((String)obj);
    }

    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return isNull((Long)obj);
    }

    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return isNull((Integer)obj);
    }

    return obj == null;
}
```

So my question: what are the benefits of calling Validator to do this function rather than simply writing `if (obj == null)`? Do these function calls add a significant enough overhead that it is worth avoiding this method of programming?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the implementation](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.1/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/Validator.java.html) of `isNull` for different types. Such as `string`:

```
public static boolean isNull(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return true;
    }

    s = s.trim();

    if ((s.length() == 0) || (s.equals(StringPool.NULL))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is not the same as `obj == null`, because if `obj` has a value of "\t ", the null comparison will return `false`. On the other hand, `isNull` will return `true` because of the `s = s.trim()` followed by `s.length() == 0`.

If you've used .NET Framework, the `isNull(String s)` is what is called [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)—a much better name for the method.

For instance, in your first piece of code, if `list` is an empty, non-null list:

- `list == null` will return `false`,
- `Validator.isNull(list)` will return `true`.

> Do these function calls add a significant enough overhead that it is worth avoiding this method of programming?

Since the method doesn't do the same thing as `obj == null`, comparing its performance makes no real sense. The caller of `isNull` uses this method because it is convenient when checking for, say, a null or empty list, or a null, empty or whitespace string.

Obviously, if the only thing you need is to check whether the variable is null, just do `obj == null`; `Validator.isNull` is not for that (despite its name).

Note that the `isNull(Object)` overload does an additional job of comparing the type of the object and eventually doing a cast. This means that when using the validator library, you should try to always work with typed variables. For instance:

```
Object obj = this.loadSomethingFromProxy();
if (Validator.isNotNull(obj))
{
    something = (Long)obj;
    this.doStuff(something);
}
```

should be refactored into:

```
Long something = (Long)this.loadSomethingFromProxy();
if (Validator.isNotNull(obj))
{
    this.doStuff(something);
}
```

because in the later case, you are doing the cast only once (instead of twice) and then call the `isNotNull(Long)` overload, skipping type checking.

Comment: Agreed! But I'm specifically asking about objects which are not predefined (i.e., Object[], Long, String). For these cases, the code defaults to just `obj == null`.

Comment: @patstuart: `isNull(Object obj)` just calls the other `isNull` methods based on the type of `obj`, so the result of this method will also be different compared to a simple `obj == null` comparison.

Comment: I know _what_ it does. I'm asking _why_ do it this way when it adds processor cycles?

Comment: @patstuart: because the intention of the caller is not to determine whether the variable is null, but to know whether the variable is null or empty or contains whitespace.

Comment: that's pretty hard to do with a _List_.